# Importing information from a plist file

Tags: plist, nsdictionary, tableview

i'm trying to view some data stored in a plist file in a TableView.
my plist has some dictionary items, each has 3 values (two strings and a number).

I didn't find any way to import all of this information conveniently into the tableView.

i'll appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Uri